# DataTable add data retrieved with AJAX to table doesn't work properly

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I've created a DataTable and I want to add some data from another file through AJAX request.

I initialized my table like this:

```
$urlo = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'AJAX-ValoriEsecuzioneLogica.php'; // my from where i need to retrieve data for my table
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    var email = <?php echo json_encode($mail); ?>;
    var urlo = <?php echo json_encode($urlo); ?>;
    $j('#example1').DataTable({
        'paging'      : true,
        'lengthChange': false,
        'searching'   : false,
        'ordering'    : true,
        'info'        : true,
        'autoWidth'   : false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : urlo+"?email="email,
            "type" : "POST",
            "data" : email,
            "dataSrc": ""
        },

    });
});
```

The problem is that i don't get anything as result, but I would like to append the data to my table.
Is there a problem in my code? How can i append data to table through AJAX call?

This is my php file with the returned data (I'm using Wordpress)

```
$mail = $_GET['email'];
// use this flag to load only wordpress core
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
$root= $root.'/wp-load.php';
require ($root);
// now you can use $wpdb
global $table_name, $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "bittrex_account_info";

function conta($mail) {
    global $wpdb, $table_name;
    $attivo = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT attivo FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));
    $mess = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT messaggio FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));
    $acquistato = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT acquistato FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));
    $test_mode = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT test_mode FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));
    $valoreAttuale = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT valoreAttuale FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));
    $guadagno = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT guadagno FROM $table_name WHERE email = %s", $mail));

    $result = ['acquistato'=>$acquistato,'test_mode'=>$test_mode,'valore_attuale'=>$valoreAttuale,'guadagno'=>$guadagno];
    echo json_encode($result);
}

// call the function and pass the parameters
conta($mail);

// close connection
$wpdb->close();
```

This is my DataTable(I won't show you very cell inside but just the important part):

```
<table class="table no-margin" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabellaAccountBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I did everything, and the table is loaded correctly. I think the problem is in the AJAX call because it isn't returning anything